# Changing dataset connection string at runtime

Tags: c#, dataset, runtime, connection-string

I have a c# generated dataset.  How can I change the connection string so I can use the dataset with another (identically structured yet differently populated) database?  This has to occur at runtime as I do not know the server or database name at compile time.  I am using c# 2.0.

Comment: http://www.csharpbydesign.com/2008/01/overriding-dataset-settings-co.html

Comment: This is going to change it globally, how about on a per instance basis?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can modify a single instance of the table adapter.

```
_myAdapter.Connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
```

Comment: The Connection Modifier must be public to be accessed outside the assembly (i.e., another project)

Comment: Is there any solution to change connectionstring of all TableAdapters in a DataSet?

Comment: @M_Mogharrabi _adapter.Fill(yourDataset);

Comment: On insert adapter, connection propery is not public.

Comment: Excellent solution!

Comment: Good Solution but for QueriesTableAdapters
Don't forget to click over the Query and F4
Then, on Connection, click on the plus (+) sign and make Modifier Public

Comment: And Before
dsTableAdapters.QueriesTableAdapter dsQueriesTableAdapter = new dsTableAdapters.QueriesTableAdapter();
After
class MydsTableAdapters : dsTableAdapters.QueriesTableAdapter
        {

            public void ChangeConnectionString(string cs)
            {
                foreach (var commandCollection in this.CommandCollection)
                {
                    commandCollection.Connection.ConnectionString = cs;
                }
            }
        }
MydsTableAdapters  dsQueriesTableAdapter = new MydsTableAdapters();

Answer (score 7):

Based on the link above, I did it this way:

```
partial class QueriesTableAdapter
{
    public QueriesTableAdapter(string connectionString)
    {
        Properties.Settings.Default["connectionString"] = connectionString;
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like how I would have done it ... Is there a problem doing it this way?

Comment: Nope, seems to work quite well and a bit nicer than the link suggests above.  Would still be nice to have a per-instance version though, but it's not a problem just yet.

Comment: Am using your code. It's work well but it only change the server address not changing database name, username and password. Please help me to do this..

Answer (score 0):

The database name is also a parameter in the connection string.