# Select connection string at runtime in c# project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-forms-designer

I am fairly new to c#. So far so good with learning. I do have one question, well maybe two.

How do you create a user dialog to allow the selection of a connection string when the project starts? I have 4 databases with the same schema and would like to allow the user to choose which to connect to when they launch the program.

I am currently using datasets but am willing to learn/try another method to acheive the desired result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put them into the config's `connectionStrings` area and provide the user with a ComboBox containing the names of the connection strings.  Then use the one selected.

In your config:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="Environment1" connectionString="connString1" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  <add name="Environment2" connectionString="connString2" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  <add name="Environment3" connectionString="connString3" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  <add name="Environment4" connectionString="connString4" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

In your code, add the connection strings to a ComboBox:

```
foreach (ConnectionStringSettings connString in ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings)
{
    myComboBox.Items.Add(connString.Name);
}
```

Get the name from the ComboBox, then get the connString you need and use it:

```
// Access chosen one:
string chosenName = (string)myComboBox.SelectedItem;
string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[chosenName].ConnectionString;
```

Comment: How would I code the DropDownList to select and then load the proper connection? My apologies for the newbie questions.

Comment: Since you're in WinForms, you want a ComboBox.  Edited to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the connection string for various database into the `app.config` or `web.config` files as suggested by **zimdanen** like:

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Database1" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial 
     Catalog=db1;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

Then you can use `ConfigurationManager` class to achieve the results:

```
foreach (ConnectionStringSettings connectionString in 
                     ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings)
 {
     //YOU CAN ADD NAME OF CONNECTION STRING TO A COMBOBOX FOR USER TO MAKE
     // A SELECTION
     //connectionString.Name
 }
```

Once the selection is made you can get the desired connection string with following line:

```
var s=ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[<SELECTED NAME>].ConnectionString
```

Comment: So far so good. Just one final question, I think. The last block of code to get the desired connection, how would I use this to make sure the dataset uses the selected connection?

Comment: How are you filling your dataset?  `s` here will contain the connection string as a string, so just pass that to wherever it's needed.

Comment: The dataset was generated by the wizard. I know, probably not the best way, but I'm learning. I see where the connection string is defined in the dataset.Designer.cs file for each TableAdapter. Where would I put the last block of code and how would I pass the string?

Comment: I really appreciate all the help. Still unsure how to pass the string. I was able to pass it using settings.settings to define it. When I run the app, I get an error "The ConnectionString property has not been initialized"

Comment: I haven't worked with wizard-based datasets.  Try this?:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/3478228/128217

Answer (score 0):

Add Application Configuration File and add your connection strings in < connectionStrings>. In your code use ConfigurationManager.ConnectionString to enumerate through a list of connection strings.